# IE support! Work around nested media queries in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries, responsive

The thing is, my HTML/CSS looks great and responsive in all browsers - except IE (only tested in IE11).
For some reason, IE misreads the padding that holds the text in place, so I figured I'd make a

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    /* some css stuff */

    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

        /* IE specific CSS within a max-width of 1200px*/
    }
}
```

to target the browser, which works great!

The problem is that using media queries to make the site responsive (not allowed to use Bootstrap or any other framework), and IE does not support nested media queries.

So now the design is no longer responsive..

Is there any workaround that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: IE **does** support media queries. That said, CSS itself does not permit **nested** `@media` queries (just use the `and` operator to combine rules) - it sounds like you're using CSS that's actually non-compliant and somehow expecting IE to behave the same as other browsers.

Comment: "The problem is that using MediaQueries to make the site responsive and IE does not support nested media queries." - as I said, "nested media queries" are not permitted by the CSS specification, so just refactor your CSS so the `@media` blocks aren't nested and it should work in all browsers.

Comment: "only tested in IE11" - you probably don't need to test even in IE11 (let alone IE10, IE9, etc) considering that IE11 is now **6.5 years old** with less than 2% worldwide usage-share, and Microsoft's flagship browser is now the Chromium-based Microsoft Edge. The only reason to support IE11 today is if you work for a nuclear-war survival bunker manufacturer that intends to power its Smart Home functionality off Windows 7 for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! But according to caniuse.com, nested mediaqueries is supported in most browsers. https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_at-rules_media_nested-queries . 
If i were to combine 2 media queries, one to check if it's IE, and one to check the screen size, how would that look? 

And i couldn't agree more about whether or not to support older versions of IE, but it's a work thing, and it's not up to me.

Comment: As I said, change your CSS to use non-nested queries. It's only a syntactic change. I cannot provide further guidance because you haven't posted your **real actual** CSS showing your nested `@media` queries.

Comment: The way i've structured it so far is: 
`@media only screen abd (max-width: 1200px){
/* some css stuff */

  @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active){
         /* IE specific CSS */
}
} `

First to handle the responsiveness, then speficy specific css for IE. 
If i were to combine these quieries, how would that look?

Comment: that's **not** a "nested" media-query - that's a normal `@media`-query. Please post a **minimal reproducible example**: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){  
/* some css stuff */  

        @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active){  
                /* IE specific CSS within a max-width of 1200px*/  
    }  
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your `@media` rules so they aren't nested - this does unfortunately mean potentially duplicating some rules (but tools like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) (or T4, if you're tightly-wedded to Visual Studio) are meant for this).

#### From this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    .rule1 {
        color: black;
    }

    .rule2 {
        color: red;
    }

    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

        /* IE specific CSS within a max-width of 1200px*/
        .ieRule1 {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

#### To this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    .rule1 {
        color: black;
    }

    .rule2 {
        color: red;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

    .rule1 {
        color: black;
    }

    .rule2 {
        color: red;
    }

    .ieRule1 {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, yes - that was a typo. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Exactly what i needed! -Thanks